# SQL Using Case with date function

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd, getdate

I'm trying to use case for date to run query in SSIS backward 1 month which is

- if this month is January must show data of December last year and
- if months are in February to December must show data of previous month.

After I run the query, it shows an error:

> incorrect syntax near month

(see the screenshot).

Can someone please provide me assistance? Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.POLICY_NO, c.CLAIM_NO, c.ENTRY_DATE, 
    c.LOSS_DATE, c.LOSS_TIME, c.LOSS_DESC_CODE, c.LOSS_DESCRIPTION,
    c.CLAIM_STATUS, c.CLAIM_TYPE, c.PERSON_ENTRY_CODE,
    (SELECT p.person_full_name 
     FROM center_setup.dbo.setup_person_name_master p
     WHERE p.person_short_name = c.person_entry_code) AS Person_Name,
    c.loss_place_name
FROM
    (SELECT
         cm.policy_no, COUNT(cm1.claim_no) AS Count_,
         cm.LOSS_DATE, 
         CASE
             WHEN MONTH(cm.ENTRY_DATE) = '01' THEN DATEADD(year, -1, cm.ENTRY_DATE)
    month(cm.ENTRY_DATE) >= '02' AND year(cm.ENTRY_DATE)=YEAR(GETDATE()) then DATEADD(month, -1, cm.ENTRY_DATE) 
         END, 
         cm.LOSS_DESC_CODE
     FROM 
         cosl_master cm 
     INNER JOIN
         cosl_master cm1 ON cm.POLICY_NO = cm1.POLICY_NO 
                         AND cm.loss_date = cm1.loss_date 
                         AND cm.loss_desc_code = cm1.LOSS_DESC_CODE 
                         AND cm1.CLAIM_STATUS <> 'I' 
                         -- AND cm.LOSS_TIME = cm1.LOSS_TIME
     WHERE
         cm.claim_status IN ('O', 'R') 
         AND cm.CLAIM_STATUS <> 'I'
     GROUP BY
         cm.claim_no, cm.policy_no, cm.LOSS_DATE, cm.ENTRY_DATE, cm.LOSS_DESC_CODE
     HAVING
         COUNT(cm1.claim_no) > 1) A 
LEFT JOIN
    COSL_MASTER c ON A.POLICY_NO = c.POLICY_NO 
                  AND c.CLAIM_STATUS <> 'I' 
                  AND a.LOSS_DATE = c.LOSS_DATE 
                  AND c.LOSS_DESC_CODE = a.LOSS_DESC_CODE
ORDER BY
    a.policy_no ASC
```

Comment: @Krittpat Somsiri I have updated my answer. You can check it. :)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed **WHEN** keyword for second test case.

```
case
   when month(cm.ENTRY_DATE) = '01' then DATEADD(year, -1, cm.ENTRY_DATE)
   when month(cm.ENTRY_DATE) >= '02' AND year(cm.ENTRY_DATE)=YEAR(GETDATE()) then DATEADD(month, -1, cm.ENTRY_DATE) 
end
```

We can directly use `DATEADD(MONTH,-1,cm.ENTRY_DATE)` without any CASE statement. We don't need to worry about year.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2023-10-01', 102)) AS PrevMonthDate
```

Output will be 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2023-01-01', 102)) AS PrevMonthDate
```

Output will be 2022-12-01 00:00:00.000.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the assistance. After I add in when into the query there is an error "No column name was specified for column 4 of 'A'"

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches to the use of CASE, so you just need to understand the correct syntax, depending on how you are going to do your CASE comparison.  (In the particular case of your error, your syntax is not quite right)

Either (a simple comparison of one value):

```
SELECT CASE month(cm.EntryDate)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'something'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'something else'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'another different thing'
END
```

or (different comparison conditions)

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN month(cm.EntryDate) = 1 THEN 'this action'
    WHEN month(cm.EntryDate) >= 2 AND year(cm.EntryDate) = year(getdate()) THEN 'a different action'
END
```